# What kind of calculations will you do in order to mimic the 3D rotation of the rectangle in 2D space?

Tags: math, 3d

You are given a rectangle with width, x and height y. You can see that first of all the rectangle rotates from the middle along the y-axis. Once the rotation is complete, it rotates along the x-axis but from the bottom.

Consider yourself to be in a 2D drawing space, as a result, you cannot use 3D transformation matrices to perform these tasks.

Comment: Edited the tags because what you're asking has nothing at all to do with Windows 7.

Comment: Also, this question doesn't make any sense except in terms of a homework question.  People use higher dimensional math to solve lower dimensional problems all the time.  See Quaternions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion, and also see Graphical Projection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you're not just representing it in 3 dimensions, doing the matrix multiplication, and displaying only the xy coordinates.

Comment: @Mike, taha: Mike's suggestion is graphical projection, specifically Orthographic Projection - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection#Orthographic_projection

Comment: "From the middle along the y-axis"? "Along the x-axis but from the bottom"? If this is for a mathematics class, the teacher is in the wrong field.

Comment: [Affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) (rotation, scaling and shear) are composable. In other words, you can rotate and translate to your hearts content in any affine space and then, as an afterthought, project on to a lower dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would use homographic coordinate vectors to describe your rectangle by appending a 1 for z to your 2D coordinates. This lets you use 3d transformation matrixes as appropriate.

Your constraint seems pointless- if the problem is data storage, simulate the appended 1 by calculating the matrix transformation with a function instead of a simple matrix multiplication.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography